Is it possible to develop an Android app that interacts with Echo Dot like the Amazon Alexa app?
I am interested in developing an Android app that can interact with the Echo Dot, similar to the functionality provided by the Amazon Alexa app, to control echo dot volume, casting audio file etc.  I would like to know if it is possible to create such an app and, if so, what technologies and frameworks are required to achieve this.
Specifically, I am looking for guidance on the following:
Can I develop an Android app that can interact with Echo Dot devices?
What APIs or SDKs are available for integrating Alexa functionalities into an Android app?
Are there any specific requirements or limitations I should be aware of when developing such an app?
Any pointers, documentation links, or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
I haven't found anything on internet about this
